# Why am I getting this UNEXPECTED HTTP error in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, http-headers, http-error

So guys i'm setting up my backend in NodeJS for an e-commerce website.
But I ran into an error trying to implement the "Order" method.

First the connection to mysql database :

```
let mysql = require('mysql')

let connection = mysql.createConnection({

    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'ecom_new'

})

connection.connect()

module.exports = connection
```

**Then in my Models there is a *Client* class that contains the following method :**

```
static order(orderData, callbackfn) {

        orderData.products.map((product) => {

            connection.query(`INSERT INTO orders SET
                product_name = ?, owner = ?, quantity = ?, price = ?, client_name = ?, client_phone = ?, client_address = ?`,
                [product.name, product.owner, product.count,product.price, orderData.clientName, 
                orderData.clientPhone, orderData.clientLoc], (err, result) => {

                    if (err) {

                        callbackfn(err)

                    } else {

                        callbackfn(null, result)

                    }

                })

        })


    }
```

**The *orderData* parameter in the *order()* method is a JSON posted from the frontend, that looks like this:**

```
{
    "products": [
        {"name": "Item 1", "owner": "Clint", "count": 1, "price": 150},
        {"name": "Item 2", "owner": "Steve", "count": 3, "price": 350},
        {"name": "Item 3", "owner": "Bruce", "count": 6, "price": 110}
     ],

    "clientName": "Tony Stark",
    "clientPhone": "111111",
    "clientLoc": "Malibu"
}
```

**And finally the route that handles this request is coded like this :**

```
router.post('/client/order', (req, res) => {


    Client.order(req.body, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {

            res.json({RequestResult: 'ERROR', Message: err['sqlMessage']})

        } else {

            res.json({RequestResult: 'SUCCESS', Message: 'New order placed successfully'})

        }

    })


})
```

It works just fine when I try (**once**) to place an order from my frontend (and Postman).

But the issue is that whenever I try (**again**) to place an order i'm getting the **[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]**  error. Looks like i can only place an order once, which is nonsense.

I don't really know what is wrong and it is keeping me from moving on to other concerns of my project, help is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add `console.log()`s to your code to figure out how far the execution gets, and which values the variables actually have?

Comment: sounds like your server side code is trying to respond to the request more than once. once the response is sent, you can't it. i don't see the code that is causing it here, but that is what you need to figure out.

Comment: Quesstor nailed it, however I'm wondering why the code works the first time and only fails on subsequent runs? With your current code you should be able to reproduce the error reliably as long as you send two or more products (also, just for readability, you should use `forEach` instead of `map` if you don't use the changed array)

Comment: @ChrisG Yes he sure did, that was also my main concern it's a weird behavior. (Alright i'm going to do that, thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you iterate over the products with `orderData.products.map((product) => {...` and for each product you call the `callbackfn` which in turn calls `res.json({...})`. So for each product a `res.json({...})` is called but i think you are only allowed to call it once per request.

Try something like this in the Client class:

```js
static order(orderData) {
  return Promise.all(orderData.products.map((product) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //run query
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve()
    })
  }))
}
```

now you can use this function like so:

```js
Client.order(req.body)
  .then(() => res.json({ RequestResult: 'SUCCESS', Message: 'New order placed successfully' }))
  .catch(err => res.json({ RequestResult: 'ERROR', Message: err['sqlMessage'] }))
```

Comment: Hey @quesstor , thank you for the explanation in the beginning it made my code's logic more clear after reading it. 
And your code is working , I just tried it. I'm really new to Promises and stuff but i'm going to take my time and try to read understand the code in details. Thanks a lot you solved my problem !!